# Trying to install Cashier on Laravel 5.4.36

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 5.4.36 and I am trying to install Cashier using these steps: https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-7-cashier-stripe-subscription-tutorial

However when I try to run this line:

```
sudo composer require laravel/cashier
```

I get this error:

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/cashier[v12.6.0, ..., v12.6.1] require illuminate/contracts ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/contra
cts[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.7, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.0, v8.0.0, ..., v8.19.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it 
conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/cashier ^12.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/cashier[v12.6.0, v12.6.1].
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Your link points to Laravel _7_ tutorial, and you're using Laravel _5_. Laravel cashier seems to require at least laravel 6.

Comment: will it mess everything up if I upgrade from 5 to 7?

Comment: Some of it, yes. You can check the migration guide in the docs.

Comment: Ughhhh, was hoping not to do that

Comment: try to install this version `composer require laravel/cashier "^7.2.2"`

Comment: Yup that wored!

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
composer require laravel/cashier
```

this will install the current version of the cashier package that works with the current version of Laravel. You have to check what version of cashier (if any), your current Laravel version installed, supports.